# Instagram Business Account and Graph API - Anyone knows how to get Story Poll votes and results?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

Although I have read Instagram Graph API and API references, I was wondering if anyone found a way to get votes and poll results of a story via API call.

Or is there any other way except web scraping to retrieve poll results information?
For example, any third-party `python` libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question!  I am also wondering the same thing; did you manage to find an answer?  Thank you!